# How to retrieve any external email address?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have code that runs when I send an email. It looks at the recipient address and the subject to see if it contains certain words and then pops up a message box to remind us to update our drawing revision control.

It works for internal email addresses and seems to work on some external email addresses. It doesn't like the email address I need to look for.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim hismail As String
Dim strSubject As String
strSubject = Item.Subject

Dim olObj As MailItem

Set olObj = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
hismail = olObj.Recipients.Item(1).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Set olObj = Nothing

If hismail = "David@abclimited.net" And strSubject Like "*update*" Or strSubject Like "*revision*" Then

    MsgBox "Dont forget to update Drawing PDF`s if necessary", vbExclamation, "Have you updated the PDF`s?"

End If
End Sub
```

I have changed the address in this post but it is the same format and length.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens exactly? Does it just not recognize the email, or is it giving you an error? Have you tried testing your `hisemail` to make sure that it is getting the address you'd expect from emails from him? I would recommend writing a simple script to print his email specifically so that you can see what the code is seeing.

Comment: Also, just a thought, his email might not be within the Exchange server, and thus you wont be able to get his `PrimarySmtpAddress` that way. This is likely why most of your internal emails, and some external emails, are working. Try accessing the `To` field instead. Or see if you can get his email from another property.

Comment: Hi sorry, there are no error messages. the email just sends with out showing the message box. I just tried sending hismail to a message box. It worked fine on my email address and returned the correct address but the address i`m trying to send to came up with a debug box saying "run time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set" adn debug highlighted this line      hismail = olObj.Recipients.Item(1).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of digging I found a solution that should get you pointed in the right direction. This is based off of the suspicion that your problem is due to your target user not being available within the Exchange server of your organization. This solution *should* solve the issue, but if it doesn't it will at least give you an idea of where to look next.

First, I took the code example from this MSDN article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient) and modified it so that it returns an array of Address Users and their emails:

```
Private Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Private Function GetSMTPAddressesForRecipients(ByVal MailItem As Outlook.MailItem) As Variant
    Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
    Set Recipients = MailItem.Recipients

    Dim Addresses As Variant
    ReDim Addresses(0 To Recipients.Count - 1, 0 To 1)

    Dim Accessor As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

    Dim Recipient As Outlook.Recipient
    For Each Recipient In Recipients
        Set Accessor = Recipient.PropertyAccessor

        Dim i As Long
        Addresses(i, 0) = Recipient.Name
        Addresses(i, 1) = Accessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)

        i = i + 1
    Next

    GetSMTPAddressesForRecipients = Addresses
End Function
```

This will loop through all recipients within the email, and capture their names and emails, putting each one into the next spot within the array. Next, we need to use this information within your routine:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Note that I explicitly convert the subject to lowercase since the patterns use lowercase
    Dim EmailSubject As String
    EmailSubject = LCase(Item.Subject)

    If EmailSubject Like "*update*" Or EmailSubject Like "*revision*" Then
        Dim Addresses As Variant
        Addresses = GetSMTPAddressesForRecipients(Item)

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(Addresses, 1) To UBound(Addresses, 1)
            If Addresses(i, 1) = "David@abclimited.net" Then
                MsgBox "Dont forget to update Drawing PDF`s if necessary", vbExclamation, "Have you updated the PDF`s?"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

A couple of things to note here. First, your pattern was using lowercase for the subject, so you will want to convert the subject to lowercase so that, if you have a subject like "Update the Revision" your pattern still catches it.

Second, I put the most likely condition up front, that is, most of your email subjects will not contain "Subject" or "Revision". There's no need to then ask the server for the addresses of the recipients. Previously, your code would get the address before checking if it needed it. Its best to only ask for what we need, it makes your code easier to read, and maintain while also reducing any processing cost.

Finally, this code will loop through **all** addresses and not just look at the first one. By doing this, you will still trigger the alert even if he is the second, or third, or fiftieth address in the list.

I hope this helps! Here's the code in entirety:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Note that I explicitly convert the subject to lowercase since the patterns use lowercase
    Dim EmailSubject As String
    EmailSubject = LCase(Item.Subject)

    If EmailSubject Like "*update*" Or EmailSubject Like "*revision*" Then
        Dim Addresses As Variant
        Addresses = GetSMTPAddressesForRecipients(Item)

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(Addresses, 1) To UBound(Addresses, 1)
            If Addresses(i, 1) = "David@abclimited.net" Then
                MsgBox "Dont forget to update Drawing PDF`s if necessary", vbExclamation, "Have you updated the PDF`s?"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetSMTPAddressesForRecipients(ByVal MailItem As Outlook.MailItem) As Variant
    Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
    Set Recipients = MailItem.Recipients

    Dim Addresses As Variant
    ReDim Addresses(0 To Recipients.Count - 1, 0 To 1)

    Dim Accessor As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

    Dim Recipient As Outlook.Recipient
    For Each Recipient In Recipients
        Set Accessor = Recipient.PropertyAccessor

        Dim i As Long
        Addresses(i, 0) = Recipient.Name
        Addresses(i, 1) = Accessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)

        i = i + 1
    Next

    GetSMTPAddressesForRecipients = Addresses
End Function
```

Comment: Mate that was awesome. You identified the problem, re-wrote the code (and it works), full explanation and loads of info. that was fantastic, thank you so much

Comment: Not a problem, its what we are here for. Best of luck! :)